# Query all documents in the collection to find if certain document contains value

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Let's say that I have thousands of documents in the mongodb collection. Every random document contains object ownersData with two properties (ownerId, ownerRef)

```
{
   "_id": {....},
   "name": "abc",
   "ownersData": { "ownerId":"1", "ownerRef":"qwer" }
   
}
```

what should be the fastest way to query all documents with info that some document contains certain ownerRef value

Comment: Creating an index on ownersData.ownerRef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have C# objects representing the data in your database, you could achieve this using linq.

```cs
public IEnumerable<Document>? GetDocumentByOwnerRef(string ownerReference)
 => dbContext.Documents.Where(d =>
      d.ownerData is not null && d.ownersData.ownerRef.Equals(ownerReference)
    ).ToList();
```

EDIT: As @SJFJ correctly pointed out in the comments; while this does work, it *will* scan your entire collection, making it a very long process. Creating an index on the `ownerRef` column in your mongodb will save performance and load time.

Comment: It is important to have an index created to prevent a full collection scan